# Angular 2 - Unit test wrong URL (Uncaught in promise)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, routes

I would like to test a wrong URL in Angular 2 unit test.
My goal is to check if that wrong url is well redirected to "/home" if that url is not recognized.

My redirect :

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
```

My test in menu.component.spec.ts :

```java
  it('should redirect wrong url to home url', async(() => {
    router.navigate(['/wrong']).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/home');
    });
  }));
```

But it end up with the error message :

> Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'wrong'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'wrong'

Is there a way to endle url that will not match with TestBed.configureTestingModule imports routes ?

**UPDATE :**
Updating my routes for redirecting wrong url solved the error

```java
imports: [FormsModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
        {
          path: '', children: [
            { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent},
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
          ]
        },
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
      ])]
```

Comment: And if you use `expect(location.path).toThrowError()` ?

Comment: can you show your routes configuration, where you are supposed to redirect wrong to home ?

Comment: @trichetriche Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: <toThrowError> : Actual is not a Function
Usage: expect(function() {<expectation>}).toThrowError(<ErrorConstructor>, <message>)

Comment: Woops, forgot the parenthesis : `expect(location.path()).toThrowError()`

Comment: That was my TestBed.configureTestingModule import declaration that was the problem. It was différent from my current app.routing.ts, after fixing that and changing my redirect to { path: '**', redirectTo: '' } and { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' } everyting got fine